# Search for every value from one array in another array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

Please, I need your help.
I have array of a date range:

```
dateRange = [1 Jun 2020, 2 Jun 2020, 3 Jun 2020, 4 Jun 2020, 5 Jun 2020];
```

and an array of offers:

```
offers = [
{DeskUID: "B200B3", Day: 1 Jun 2020}
{DeskUID: "B200B3", Day: 2 Jun 2020}
{DeskUID: "B200B3", Day: 3 Jun 2020}
{DeskUID: "B200B3", Day: 4 Jun 2020}
{DeskUID: "B200B3", Day: 5 Jun 2020}
{DeskUID: "B211B5", Day: 3 Jun 2020}
{DeskUID: "B211B5", Day: 4 Jun 2020}
]
```

How to create a result array where will be just offers from offers array which have entries for every single day in the dateRange array?

```
result = [
{DeskUID: "B200B3", Day: 1 Jun 2020}
{DeskUID: "B200B3", Day: 2 Jun 2020}
{DeskUID: "B200B3", Day: 3 Jun 2020}
{DeskUID: "B200B3", Day: 4 Jun 2020}
{DeskUID: "B200B3", Day: 5 Jun 2020}
]
```

The solution has to work in IE11 - no arrow functions,...

EDIT:
If I have offers array like the below, your function gives me wrong results.

```
dateRange = ['1 Jun 2020', '2 Jun 2020', '3 Jun 2020']

offers = [ 
    {DeskUID: "B201A10", Day: '1 Jun 2020'} 
    {DeskUID: "B201A10", Day: '2 Jun 2020'} 
    {DeskUID: "B211A15", Day: '1 Jun 2020'} 
    {DeskUID: "B211A15", Day: '2 Jun 2020'} 
    {DeskUID: "B211A15", Day: '3 Jun 2020'} 
    ]

result = [
    {DeskUID: "B201A10", Day: '1 Jun 2020'} 
    {DeskUID: "B201A10", Day: '2 Jun 2020'} 
    {DeskUID: "B211A15", Day: '3 Jun 2020'} 
    ]

expected result = [
    {DeskUID: "B201A15", Day: '1 Jun 2020'} 
    {DeskUID: "B201A15", Day: '2 Jun 2020'} 
    {DeskUID: "B201A15", Day: '3 Jun 2020'} 
    ]
```

Comment: it doesnt  make sense, based on your input array which should be an array. not an object the result should be the same as the input

Comment: @eugensunic
dateRange is an array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uses a Set() to keep track of found Day matches, and return the DeskUID Days that contains all matches.  You also haven't made clear if you want to only match if the offers contains *exactly only those Days* or just needs to include them.

You didn't state what to do with dupes, so I'm just including them if you want non-matches included, and excluding if you only want matches.

```js
dateRangeArray = ['1 Jun 2020', '2 Jun 2020', '3 Jun 2020']

offers = [{
  DeskUID: "B201A10",
  Day: '30 May 2020'
},{
  DeskUID: "B201A10",
  Day: '1 Jun 2020'
}, {
  DeskUID: "B201A10",
  Day: '2 Jun 2020'
}, {
  DeskUID: "B211A15",
  Day: '1 Jun 2020'
}, {
  DeskUID: "B211A15",
  Day: '2 Jun 2020'
}, {
  DeskUID: "B211A15",
  Day: '3 Jun 2020'
}, {
  DeskUID: "B211A15",
  Day: '4 Jun 2020'
}, {
  DeskUID: "B211A15",
  Day: '3 Jun 2020'
}]

// include non-match Day but match DeskUID contains all Day
var dateRange = new Set()
// Set() constructor is buggy under IE11
dateRangeArray.forEach(function(x){dateRange.add(x)})
var result = [], acc = {};
for(var i = 0; i < offers.length; i++) {
  var offer = offers[i]
  var days = acc[offer.DeskUID] = acc[offer.DeskUID] || [new Set(),[]]
  days[1].push(offer)
  if(dateRange.has(offer.Day)) {
    days[0].add(offer.Day)
  }
  if (days[0].size === dateRange.size) result = days[1]
}


console.log("include non-match Days:" + JSON.stringify(result));

// include only matches Day and exclude dupes
var dateRange = new Set()
// Set() constructor is buggy under IE11
dateRangeArray.forEach(function(x){dateRange.add(x)})
var result = [], acc = {};
for(var i = 0; i < offers.length; i++) {
  var offer = offers[i]
  var days = acc[offer.DeskUID] = acc[offer.DeskUID] || [new Set(),[]]
  if(dateRange.has(offer.Day) && !days[0].has(offer.Day)) {
    days[1].push(offer)
  }
  if(dateRange.has(offer.Day)) {
    days[0].add(offer.Day)
  }
  if (days[0].size === dateRange.size) result = days[1]
}

console.log("include only match Days no dupes:" + JSON.stringify(result));
```

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I tried to implement your code but I get this error in the console: TypeError: Object.values(...).find(...) is undefined

Comment: Was using some features that don't work in IE11.  should be working now

Comment: I appreciate your help, unfortunately, your both functions give me an empty array.

Comment: Did you run my example in the answer above?  It shouldn't return an empty array.  Please showwhat input you are using that is causing empty array

Comment: There's a problem with Set() constructor being buggy that was fixed

Comment: I think there is a problem with the dates. Shouldn't be there implemented something like this? new Date(offer.Day).getTime()

Comment: That depends on the format of your date strings.  Your example indicates a notation that is just a string that can be directly compared.  There is no need to convert to a Date object.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want something like this ?

```js
var dateRange = ['1 Jun 2020', '2 Jun 2020', '3 Jun 2020', '4 Jun 2020', '5 Jun 2020'];
var offers = [{DeskUID: "B200B3", Day: '1 Jun 2020'},{DeskUID: "B200B3", Day: '2 Jun 2020'},{DeskUID: "B200B3", Day: '3 Jun 2020'},{DeskUID: "B200B3", Day: '4 Jun 2020'},{DeskUID: "B200B3", Day: '5 Jun 2020'},{DeskUID: "B211B5", Day: '3 Jun 2020'},{DeskUID: "B211B5", Day: '4 Jun 2020'}];

var result = dateRange.map(function(date){
  return offers.find(function(offer){
      return new Date(offer.Day).getTime() == new Date(date).getTime(); 
  })
});

console.log(result);
```

**UPDATE**

```js
var dateRange = ['1 Jun 2020', '2 Jun 2020', '3 Jun 2020', '4 Jun 2020', '5 Jun 2020'];
var offers = [{DeskUID: "B200B3", Day: '1 Jun 2020'},{DeskUID: "B200B3", Day: '2 Jun 2020'},{DeskUID: "B200B3", Day: '3 Jun 2020'},{DeskUID: "B200B3", Day: '4 Jun 2020'},{DeskUID: "B200B3", Day: '5 Jun 2020'},{DeskUID: "B211B5", Day: '3 Jun 2020'},{DeskUID: "B211B5", Day: '4 Jun 2020'}];

var result = Object.values(offers.reduce((acc, elem)=>{
 acc[elem.DeskUID] = acc[elem.DeskUID] || [];
 acc[elem.DeskUID].push(elem);
 return acc;
},{})).filter(elem=>elem.length == dateRange.length)[0];

console.log(result);
```

Comment: This is it! Thank you! But your code cannot read my date values.
They are not strings. Could you adjust the code, please?

I have something like this in another function but I don't know how to implement it to this one.
```
   function sameDay(d1, d2) {
    return (
    d1.getFullYear() === d2.getFullYear() &&
    d1.getMonth() === d2.getMonth() &&
    d1.getDate() === d2.getDate()
    );
   }
```

Comment: @Milan, I have edited my answer, take a look. You do not have to do the extra stuff, just get the `getTime` of date and match it.

Comment: Thank you, I got some results now but they are not correct. I edited my question, please, read EDIT. I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Thank you Gorak, this do the thing but your function ignores more next new offers. If I add a new offer into offers array with another DeskUID and with the same date range as in the dateRange array, then I get just one DeskUID in the result, expected both DeskUID, or three etc. Yes, I didn't define this enough...